# The difference between enclosing the reg-ex between double quotes in grep and providing the reg-ex as it is

Tags: regex, bash

This is the output of the ls -R command :

```
.:
compare.sh   searchByFile.sh   startup.sh   temp.txt  test.sh
compare.sh~  searchByFile.sh~  startup.sh~  test      test.sh~

./test:
test.c  test.txt  test.txt~
```

I want to isolate the files that have ".c" extension

so I do this : `ls -R | grep \.c` and this is the output I get :

```
searchByFile.sh
searchByFile.sh~
test.c
```

However when I do this : `ls -R | grep "\.c"` I get the correct output :

```
test.c
```

Why is this happening. What is the difference between `grep "\.c"` and  `grep \.c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is easily illustrated with

```
$ echo "\.c" \.c
\.c .c
$
```

Inside double quotes, the backslash is passed to the command — `echo` or `grep`. Outside double quotes, the backslash is not passed.  That explains the difference.

For the rest, see the Bash manual on [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting).

Comment: Ok now I understand. all I had to do was grep \\.c as '\' is a special character in bash aswell

Comment: could you double escape it to create a literal backslash? ie does `grep \\.c` work (no shell handy)?

Comment: Yes, you could use `echo \\.c` and you would get `\.c` as output.  Note that `echo "\\.c"` also generates `\.c` as output.  Single quotes can be easier to understand.